# Stored procedure could not be found Java

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

[App looks like this](https://s10.postimg.org/adul50iux/Screenshot_3.png)

In my Database class I have a method connect() and generateCSV(),
First one looks like this:

```
public void connect() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Begining of connect method");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("Driver not found");
    }

    String ser = "<ser name>"; 
    String user = "<user name>";
    String pass = "<password>";

    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + ser + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + pass; 
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

    System.out.println("Connected! " + con);
}
```

and the second one generateCSV() like this

```
public void generate_CSV(String db,String tbl,String date, String out) {

    try {
        connect();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        CallableStatement st = con
                .prepareCall("{call dbo.generate_CSV(?,?,?,?)}");
        st.setEscapeProcessing(true);

            st.setString(1, db);
            st.setString(2, tbl);
            st.setString(3, date);
            st.setString(4, out);

            rs= st.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I fire event and call generateCSV method, method will call connect() and connect to the server and afterwards call my procedure written in mssql.

Unfortunately I receive this...

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored
>   procedure 'dbo.generate_CSV'.

What am I missing?

I tried it without specifying the schema but nothing changes.

Comment: Check the permission of stored procedure

Comment: I granted exec permission to myself, nothing changes.